# No audio in Mac OS X on brand new iMac

Tags: mac, audio

I primarily use my Mac for iOS development, so I rarely use audio and I commonly have it turned of to not disturb my co-workers. Therefore I'm not really sure when it stopped working.

Anyway, today I wanted to play a song, but I got no audio. I rebooted the Mac and still nothing. I rebooted again and noticed that the boot sound played, but once I entered OS X I couldn't get any sound to play.

What's up with that?

Comment: What appears under output devices on the output tab in sound preferences?

Comment: Well, it works now, but there's something called Soundflower (2ch) and Soundflower (16ch) in addition to the built in speakers. I suppose the problem might have been that one of those were selected as output device.

Comment: Soundflower is an internal audio routing system that is VERY 3rd party. You must have installed it separately, and that absolutely could have been your problem.

Comment: @NReilingh seems like something Plex installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I connected and disconnected my headphones and now I have audio again.

Comment: This still happens on brand new Macs? Anyway, don't forget to accept this answer even though you posted it yourself.

Comment: @Lri I know, but I can't accept it for another two days.